# JWindow - Always on top, but below system bars?

Tags: java, swing, taskbar, always-on-top, jwindow

I've been making a program that monitors a remote system and displays non-invasive alerts in one of the corners of the screen (user preference) to alert the user to changes in the remote system.  To do this, I'm using a JWindow so that I can produce a pulsing effect for more important alerts, to draw the user's attention.  I also have an alert that scrolls its way onto the screen from off-screen.

The problem I'm having is that, if I don't set these alerts to **always on top**, they don't always display, but when I do set them always on top, the scrolling option also displays **above** the taskbar.  Is there any way that I can force it to display over all other programs (full-screen programs need not apply), but below the taskbar?

**Edit:**  Here is my code for scrolling the JWindow on/off screen:

**Edit2**: Updated code to show my incorporation of NESPowerGlove's answer:

```
public void scrollOn() {
    //Get the normal screen area minus taskbar
    Insets scnMax = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(getGraphicsConfiguration());
    int taskBar = scnMax.bottom; //Bottom of the normal window area
    int x = screenSize.width - getWidth(); //Horizontal start point of the window
    int yEnd = screenSize.height - taskBar - getHeight(); //where the window will stop
    int yStart = screenSize.height; //Vertical start point of the window
    setLocation(x,yStart); //set window to start location
    int current = yStart; //windows current location
    newHeight = yStart - current; //Set the newHeight field to the clipping start height
    while(current > yEnd) { //loop while window is still enroute to final destination
        current-=2; //increments to move the window, in pixels
        newHeight = yStart - current; //Update the newHeight field to clip the window appropriately based on position
        setLocation(x,current); //move the window to the next position
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
//This is basically the reverse of the scrollOn() method
public void scrollOff() {
    Insets scnMax = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(getGraphicsConfiguration());
    int taskBar = scnMax.bottom;
    int x = screenSize.width - getWidth();
    int yEnd = screenSize.height - taskBar;
    int yStart = this.getBounds().y;
    setLocation(x,yStart);
    int current = yStart;
    newHeight = this.getBounds().height;
    while(current < yEnd) {
        current+=2;
        newHeight = yEnd - current;
        setLocation(x,current);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //Tells the system the next alert can be triggered
    //This prevents screen clutter from multiple alerts by setting up a queue
    Main.alertControl.setAlertActive(false); 
}
```

And below is how I'm actually constructing the window (currently).  This method is just a placeholder until I get the images to build the final L&F window.

```
public AlertScroller(String msg) {
    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
            //Sets the area to be shown while the rest is clipped,
            //updating whenever the component moves
            setShape(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth(), newHeight));
            if(!isVisible())
                setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(compound);
        panel.setBackground(Color.yellow);

    JLabel imgLbl = new JLabel(msg);
        imgLbl.setFont(new Font(null,Font.BOLD,16));

    panel.add(imgLbl);
    setContentPane(panel);
    pack();

    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent click) {
            if(SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(click)) {
                autoClear = false;
                scrollOff();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it could be possible with undecorated modal JDialog

Comment: Doesn't that pull focus to the JDialog, then?  I'm trying not to pull the focus away from the user's currently active window, if possible, as I don't want to interrupt their workflow.  Also, thanks for adding the swing tag... forgot that one.

Comment: here is a few good workarounds for How to set Focus to popup JDialog/JWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could avoid displaying the JWindow over the task bar (or other similar areas you want to avoid) by figuring out the bounds of the usual area that window frames are displayed within:

```
Rectangle maxBounds = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
```

Edit: More code for animation issue that the author of question has mentioned in the comments section of this answer that he wants also included in answer:

With this I think you could make the frame undecorated (setUndecorated(true)), then make the background completely transparent and then slowly increase the height of a rectangle you draw in the background which will eventually color in the entire window.

[Here's a link that describes how to make a transparent frame and to provide opaque shaped backgrounds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html#shaped). In your case, change:

```
setShape(new Ellipse2D.Double(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight()));
```

to (and call often to slowly update the position of the Rectangle by updating newHeightOfDisplay first)

```
setShape(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, getHeight() - newHeightOfDisplay, getWidth(), newHeightOfDisplay));
```

Comment: Hmm, so basically, you're saying to mask off the window while it's "under" the taskbar, then allow it to show as it comes out from under it?  The way I have it now, it simply starts from off-screen and scrolls on.  I haven't really figured out masking off parts of the window, yet.

Comment: I'm saying don't make the bounds of your JWindow go outside the bounds returned by getMaximumWindowBounds(). You can make your application look as if it did scroll up from underneath the task bar in a few ways. One way, assuming you are using an already undecorated window without borders or title bar is to make it always above the taskbar, but slowly increase the height the background starts being opaque, the same height calculation can be used in padding what height your first panel of your GUI shows at, so the gui tracks the latest opaque height. Another way (continued in next comment)

Comment: Another way is to simply make your JWindow start out with a height of 1 and slowly increase it's height and y position (like, by 1 pixel every x milliseconds with a SwingTimer, same timer mechanism could be used with the first suggestion too).

Comment: Hmm, the first option sounds like what I'd like to do; I'm just not sure how to do the partial opaque part on the window.  The window will be using the `BoarderLayout` or custom positioning to build a custom "Look and Feel" using multiple images; static corners and dynamically scalable sides and top/bottom/center so it can be resized to fit the alert message size.

Comment: Added some samples, of what I'm currently doing for the alert window, to the OP.

Comment: I think you could make the frame undecorated (setUndecorated(true)), then [make the background completely transparent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) and then slowly increase the height of a rectangle you draw in the background which will eventually color in the entire window.

Comment: "then make the background completely transparent and then slowly increase the height of a rectangle you draw in the background "  That sounds perfect.  Could you provide some example code regarding this?  I'd like to mark that as the correct answer!

Comment: Okay I updated the answer to include code that solves the animation issue you have too.

Comment: Had to do some fiddling to get it to work when scrolling onto the screen from the bottom... Looks like the method you gave me is for scrolling down from the top (which I'll also be using).  Either way, thanks a ton for the help!  I'll be editing my OP to show what I did in my code to get it working in case anyone else wants to use it.  I do have one small problem... though it may be better in another thread as it's related to the listeners.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether it is a recommended practice but the following does what you want:

```
while(tillYouWantToDisplay) {
    window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    window.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
    delay(delayTime);   // You have to write this method using sleep()
                        // delayTime may be about 500ms
}
window.dispose();
```

You may have to put the above code in a thread.

I have written quick demo code below to show what I meant (just run it to see):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JWindow;

public class TestProgram extends JWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestProgram window = new TestProgram();
        window.setVisible(true);

        Dimension windowDim = window.getSize();
        int steps = 20;
        for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
            window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            window.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
            Point p = window.getLocation();
            window.setLocation(p.x, p.y - windowDim.height / steps);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            window.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
            window.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            window.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
            Point p = window.getLocation();
            window.setLocation(p.x, p.y + windowDim.height / steps);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        window.dispose();
    }

    public TestProgram() {
        setSize(200, 100);
        Rectangle scrDim = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
        setLocation(scrDim.x + scrDim.width - getSize().width, scrDim.y + scrDim.height);

        JLabel msg = new JLabel("Your Message");
        msg.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        msg.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(msg);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually had considered this, but it kind of defeats the purpose of having the window scroll onto the screen, then.  The main purpose of the scrolling is to draw the user's eye with the movement.

Comment: Hmm, the edit does work, though there is a bit of flicker (between being above/below).  Upvote for doing what was asked for in OP, but I do prefer NESPowerGlove's method as it has a more professional feel to it than my originally asked for method; and there's no flicker.  I can probably use your method somewhere else, however.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: Oh, side note: Be sure to add a comment when you edit your answers, if someone's already responded to it.  Edits don't trigger an alert, so I only saw it because I refreshed the page.